# How to share folders b/n VirtualBox and Win 7 using NAT adapter and Samba

Tags: linux, samba, nat

When I had my Adapter set to `Host Only` I followed [**this tutorial**](http://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/05/25/how-to-install-samba-server-on-centos-6/) and was able to view the folder `# \samba\share\` only buy typing `\\192.168.55.444` in my windows start up. So, this means I could share this folder without any problem between two machines. But, now that I have switched to [NAT adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/738196/unable-to-access-localhost-internet-using-one-adapter-in-centos), and my `ifconfig eth0` shows this as the host address `10.0.2.15` I am unable to access my samba shared folder no matter how I try to access it.

Answer (score 6):

You can have two network adapters configured and use them at the same time. Use the Host-only as well as the NAT adapter. In the Virtualbox settings page just add another network adapter.

Comment: With this I was able to finally access guest shared folders from the host

Answer (score 3):

In your VirtualBox GUI click on your VM.
   - then click Settings (Ctrl+S)
   - click Network
   - click Advanced
   - click Port Forwarding

Configure port forwarding on ports 139 and 445

This port forwarding setup will work only if you don't have samba on your HOST machine, otherwise those port are reserved so virtualbox can not take them over to forward to your guest machine.

Better solution to share files between Host and Guest machine is to install and configure VirtualBox Guest Additions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I could not get guest additions to work. I have been trying literally for weeks. And I have finally given up. But, I don't understand about the port forwarding. Do I just enter the ports? What about the IP? Leave them blank?

Comment: I know this is old, but if you couldnt get guest add's working, wanted to note that you need to mount the drive after each reboot, until you get it into fstab

Answer (score 1):

What OS do you have installed on yor VM ¿? ... The only way (for me to know) for get in work the share over NAT it's with the VBox Guest Additions...

It is not very difficult to install the guest additions; assuming you have an *buntu OS Family, mint or even debian linux, you can try this tutorials...

[DEBIAN](http://virtualboxes.org/doc/installing-guest-additions-on-debian/)
[*BUNTU](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-1957309/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-linux-mint.html)

Then you can test the connection again ...

Comment: I have CentOs 6.4. I hope you have some experience with it, because it is driving me crazy

Comment: Directly from the [wiki -->](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/), and from the [Official -->](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox/CentOSguest) sorry for my english :)